# Запись файлов в бд

Tags: php

Можно ли записать в бд txt файл? или только его содержимое?

Comment: Да, можно. В MySQL, например, есть такой тип данных "BLOB". Он предназначен для хранения бинарных данных.

Comment: Чем в Вашем понимании отличается "файл" от "его содержимого"???

Comment: @Akina у файла, как правило, есть путь и аттрибуты...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Хотелось бы именно это или нечто иное услышать от автора.